# iterate php array after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, call

i got an ajax function that calls a php who returns an array:

```
<?php
$testing = array("one","two","three", "four");   
echo json_encode($testing);        
?>
```

i call it with this ajax call;

```
$.ajax({
url:"ajax_response.php",
type:"POST",   
success:function(msg)
{
  var array = msg;    
  var test = array[2];      
  alert(test);
}
});
```

the problem is that i want to get array[1] as "one" and im geting 1 character on every array position ex: array[0] = "o", array[1] = "n", array[2] = "e". Its like the json encode or semething is spliting my array variables into characters.

Any help ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse your answer. Easiest way would be to put a `dataType` to your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_response.php",
    dataType: 'json', // add the dataType
    type: "POST",   
    success: function(msg) {
        var array = msg;    
        var test = array[2];      
        alert(test);
    }
});
```

Or you can parse it "by hand". This is sometimes necessary:

```
success: function(msg) {
    var array = JSON.parse(msg); // or parse it manually
    var test = array[2];      
    alert(test);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your response is in string format  try this at your success function

```
success:function(msg)
{
  var array ;
 eval('array ='+msg );  
  var test = array[2];      
  alert(test);
}
```

Comment: @VainFellowman child should not get gun but it is not so that gun is useless

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Well, EVER might be extreme, but here it is NOT the right tool. Not at all.

Comment: @VainFellowman yes , I also donot fever it but I have had some problem with JSON as browser compatibility in early days so have just pasted that code I have used

Comment: You are right, in older days. But there are other approaches, like JSON parse and stringify libraries.

Comment: @VainFellowman So let it be here, I am not gonna delete my answer, if nothing else work, It will work :)

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to point out the better solution, and the risk of using eval().